# How many poker hands contain exactly one ace?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm getting tripped up because of the "exactly" part.  Can anyone explain how to approach this problem and ones that may be similar.  For example, if I wanted a hand that contained exactly three K's, or one K and three 9's.

Comment: One thing that may be helpful if you are stuck is to solve a simpler problem where you can enumerate things to make sure that you have your reasoning right.  For example, you could ask yourself how many 3-card poker hands with 1 ace can you make from a deck of cards that has 2 aces and 5 non-aces.  Varying the small numbers can also help you find patterns that might allow you to guess the form of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four ways to pick an ace.  The remaining four cards cannot be an ace, and so there are $\binom{48}{4}$ ways to choose them.

**Answer.** $4\binom{48}{4}$.